# What def from python means in C

Tags: python, c

It may be a dumb question but what kind of data type is a `def` from Python in C ?

like int, uint32_t etc.. or nothing of all of this ?

Thanks

Comment: In python, variables do not have explicit types. You can assign a value of any type to a variable created with `def`.

Comment: In your words, what does `def` do in Python?

Comment: Function is a type in Python but the name of a function in C by itself is a function pointer. If you meant a function by `def`.

Answer (score 6):

`def` is a keyword in python. (It introduces the definition of functions.) It is not a datatype at all.

Answer (score 0):

`def` is the Python's keyword that is used at the start of the function/method definition.

Answer (score 0):

C and Python are fundamentally different languages and doing a line by line translation is impossible. To answer your direct question, `def` is a keyword in Python that only marks the start of a function declaration. There is no such keyword in C. Sure, you need keywords to declare functions, but there is no single keyword that is required.

Furthermore, you cannot compare types either. C has a sh*tload of different types just for integers. Python3 only has one, and it has unlimited precision. Such a type does not exist in C, although there are libraries that provides the same functionality.